# Is this undefined behaviour and why?

Tags: c++

Please, explain why this code is correct or why not:
In my opinion, line ++*p1 = *p2++ has undefined behaviour, because p1 is dereferenced first and then incrementing.

```
int main()
{
   char a[] = "Hello";
   char b[] = "World";

   char* p1 = a;
   char* p2 = b;

   //*++p1 = *p2++; // is this OK?
   ++*p1 = *p2++; // is this OK? Or this is UB?

   std::cout << a << "\n" << b;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why everyone this morning asks questions about grouping arbitrary `++`, `*` and `=` in one horribly complex and hard-to-read line...

Comment: If you have to try and figure out whether the code will explode horribly and cause the apocalypse or not, **don't use it**. Regardless of how well-defined it is, it's *not good code*.

Comment: If it's not easily readable and transparent, it's not okay.

Comment: I wish the standard would define "stupid behaviour"

Comment: Also: in this situation, I would expect anyone to actually write something like: `std::string a = "Hello"; std::string b = "World"; a = b;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is ok

```
*++p1 = *p2++ // p1++; *p1 = *p2; p2++;
```

the second is UB with C++ because you are modifying what is pointed by `p1` twice (once because of increment and once because of assignment) and there are no sequence points separating the two side effects.

With C++0x rules things are different and more complex to explain and to understand. If you write intentionally expressions like the second one, if it's not for a code golf competition and if you are working for me then consider yourself fired (even if that is legal in C++0x).

I don't know if it is legal in C++0x and I don't want to know. I've too few neurons to waste them this way.

Comment: +1: For the "consider yourself fired": that made me laugh. Smartness is proven by being able to write simple code, not by writing horribly complex lines of code.

Comment: The second is not UB in both C++03 and C++11.

Comment: @SergeDundich: The C++ standard requires that "Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression". The second case in the question is a single expression without sequence points and is writing to the same scalar value twice.

Comment: It's just as undefined in C++11: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Mike Seymour: One sentence before you have quoted: "The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator."

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++ (at least C++ 2011 and later) neither is **undefined behavior**. And even neither is **implementation defined** or **unspecified**. (All three terms are different things.)

These two lines are both well defined (but they do different things).
When you have pointers p1 and p2 to scalar types then

```
*++p1 = *p2++;
```

is equivalent to

```
p1 = p1 + 1;
*p1 = *p2;
p2 = p2 + 1;
```

(^^^this is also true for C++ 1998/2003)

and

```
++*p1 = *p2++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*p1 = *p1 + 1;
*p1 = *p2;
p2 = p2 + 1;
```

(^^^maybe also in C++ 1998/2003 or maybe not - as explained below)

Obviously in case 2 incrementing value and then assigning to it (thus overwriting just incremented value) is pointless - but there may be similar examples that make sense (e.g. `+=` instead of `=`).

**BUT like many people point out - just don't write the code that looks ambiguous or unreasonably complex. Write the code that is clear to you and supposed to be clear to the readers.**

**Old C++ 1998/2003 case for second expression is a strange matter:**

At first after reading the description of prefix increment operator:

> **ISO/IEC 14882-2003 5.3.2:**
>
> 1. The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it
>    is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable
>    lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a
>    pointer to a completely-defined object type. **The value is the new
>    value of the operand; it is an lvalue.** If x is not of type bool, the
>    expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1.

I personally have a strong feeling that everything is perfectly defined and obvious and the same as above for C++ 2011 and later.
At least in the sense that every reasonable C++ implementation will behave in exact same well defined way (including old ones).

Why it should be otherwise if we always intuitively rely on a general rule that in any simple operator evaluation within a complex expression we evaluate its operands first and **after that** apply the operator to the values of those operands. Right? Breaking this intuitive expectation would be extremely stupid for any programming language.

So for the full expression `++*p1 = *p2++;` we have operands: 1 - `++*p1` evaluated as already incremented lvalue (as defined in the above quote from C++ 2003) and 2 - `*p2++` that is an rvalue stored at pointer `p2` before its increment. It doesn't look ambiguous at all. Of course in this case - no reason to increment a value you are overwriting anyway BUT if there was double increment instead - `++(++*p1);` OR other kind of assignment like `+=`/`-=`/`&=`/`*=`/etc instead of simple assignment THAT would not be unreasonable at all.

Unfortunately all the intuition and logic is messed up by this:

**ISO/IEC 14882-2003 - 5 Expressions:**

> 4. Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands
>    of individual operators and subexpressions of individual
>    expressions, and the order in which side effects
>    take place, is unspecified. **Between the previous
>    and next *sequence point* a scalar object shall have its
>    stored value modified at most once by the evaluation
>    of an expression.** Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>    accessed only to determine the value to be stored.
>    **The requirements of this paragraph shall be met for each
>    allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full
>    expression; otherwise the *behavior is undefined*.**

> ```
>   [Example:
>       i = v[i++];         // the behavior is unspecified
>       i = 7, i++, i++;    // i becomes 9
>       i = ++i + 1;        // the behavior is unspecified
>       i = i + 1;          // the value of i is incremented
>   —end example]
> ```

So this wording **if interpreted in a paranoid way** seems to imply that modification of a value stored in a specific location more than once without intervening **sequence point** is explicitly forbidden by this rule and the last sentence declares that failing to comply with every requirement is **Undefined Behavior**. AND *our expression seems to modify the same location more that once* (**?**) with no sequence point until the full expression evaluated. (This arbitrary and unreasonable limitation is reinforced further by example 3 - `i = ++i + 1;` though it says `// the behavior is unspecified` - not **undefined** as in the wording before - which only adds more confusion.)

**BUT on the other hand...** If we ignore the example 3. (Maybe `i = ++i + 1;` is a typo and there should have been postfix increment instead - `i = i++ + 1;`? Who knows... Anyway examples are not part of formal specification.) **If we interpret this wording in the most permissive way** - we can see that in each allowed order of evaluation of subexpressions of the whole expression - preincrement `++*p1` must be evaluated to an LVALUE (which is **something that allows further modification**) **BEFORE** applying assignment operator so the only valid final value at that location is the one that is stored with assignment operator. **ALSO NOTE** that conforming C++ implementation have no obligation to actually modify that location more than once and may instead store only final result - that is both reasonable optimization allowed by the standard and may be actual demand of this article.

Which one of those interpretations is correct? Paranoid or permissive? Universally applicable logic or some suspicious and ambiguous words in a document almost nobody really ever read? Blue pill or Red pill?

Who knows... It looks like a gray area that requires less ambiguous explanation.

If we interpret the quote from C++ 2003 standard above in a paranoid way then it looks like this code may be Undefined Behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

#define INC(x) (++(x))

int main()
{
    int a = 5;

    INC(INC(a));
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

while this code is perfectly legitimate and well defined:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> T& INC(T& x) // sequence point after evaluation of the arguments
{                              // and before execution of the function body
    return ++x;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;

    INC(INC(a));
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Really?

All this looks very much like a defect of the old C++ standard.

Fortunately this has been addressed in newer C++ standards (starting with C++ 2011) as there is no such concept as **sequence point** anymore. Instead there is a relation - *something **sequenced before** something*. And of course the natural guarantee that evaluation of the argument expressions of any operator is **sequenced before** evaluation of the result of the operator is there.

> **ISO/IEC 14882-2011 - 1.9 Program execution**
>
> 13. *Sequenced before* is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation between evaluations executed by a single thread (1.10), which induces
>     a partial order among those evaluations. Given any two evaluations A
>     and B, if A is sequenced before B, then the execution of A shall
>     precede the execution of B. If A is not sequenced before B and B is
>     not sequenced before A, then A and B are *unsequenced*. [ Note: The
>     execution of unsequenced evaluations can overlap. — end note ]
>     Evaluations A and B are *indeterminately sequenced* when either A is
>     sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified
>     which. [ Note: Indeterminately sequenced evaluations cannot overlap,
>     but either could be executed first. — end note ]
> 14. Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>     effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.
> 15. Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>     and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [
>     Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the
>     execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced
>     evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently
>     in different evaluations. — end note ] **The value computations of the
>     operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of
>     the result of the operator.** If a side effect on a scalar object is
>     unsequenced relative to either anotherside effect on the same scalar
>     object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>     object, the behavior is undefined.

> ```
>   [ Example:
>       void f(int, int);
>       void g(int i, int* v) {
>       i = v[i++];         // the behavior is undefined
>       i = 7, i++, i++;    // i becomes 9
>       i = i++ + 1;        // the behavior is undefined
>       i = i + 1;          // the value of i is incremented
>       f(i = -1, i = -1);  // the behavior is undefined
>   }
>   — end example ]
> ```

(Also NOTE how C++ 2003 prefix increment example `i = ++i + 1;` is replaced by postfix increment example `i = i++ + 1;` in this C++ 2011 quote. :) )

Comment: In the second expression you have the lvalue `*p1` altered twice (increment and assignment) in a single expression without sequence points and this is UB in C++. Why do you think it's legal in this case?

Comment: @6502: "In the second expression you have the lvalue `*p1` altered twice" No. Lvalue `*p1` is altered once - by `operator++`. And after that lvalue `++(*p)` (which is a return value of `operator++`) is altered by assignment operator.

Comment: @6502: Besides even if there would be no sequence points between evaluation two expressions (like e.g. `f( ++x, ++x )`) then the order of evaluation of such expression is **unspecified** so there still would be no **undefined behavior**.

Comment: The `f(++x, ++x)` case is irrelevant, those are two distinct (sub)expressions. In the case of the question instead it's a single expression where the same object is modified twice. Moreover `++x` does not "return" anything for native types: the value of `++x` is `x` and there is a side effect of incrementing `x`. The two assignments are in the same expression without sequence points and that is what makes the expression UB ("Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression").

Comment: @6502: <<Moreover ++x does not "return" anything for native types: the value of ++x is x and there is a side effect of incrementing x.>> It is playing with the words. The fact is that for integrated types the value of prefix increment is already incremented and it is lvalue. And there is only one assignment - assignment to the value `++(*p1)` which is already incremented lvalue according to the standard (see ISO/IEC 14882-2003 5.3.2(1))

Comment: The standard discuss assignment and augmented assignment in the same place, and also says that `++x` is equivalent to `(x+=1)`. Now how can you say that the expression `(x+=1)=2` for native types does not contain two assignments without intervening sequence points is really beyond me. True that the standard is not a theorem and in a quite few places is fuzzy and not 100% clear... but this is NOT one of those cases. Preincrementing and assigning the same native type in a single expression without sequence points is UB in C++03. Fullstop. C++11 is instead a totally different game however...